# How can I measure the total time a user spends online with InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I'm measuring how long users are logged into a service. Every minute, for each user, their new total online time is sent to InfluxDB. I'd like to graph, in Grafana, the cumulative online time for all users.

What kind of query would I need to do that? I initially thought that I'd want sum(onlineTime) and group by time(1m), but I realized that's summing the values within that timeframe, not summing the totals of all users, so when a user wasn't logged in, the total would drop, because there were not data points for them.

I'm a bit confused about what I'm doing now. If I'm sending the wrong data, I can change that too.

Answer (score 0):

So this depends on the time data you send back to InfluxDB

1. The time data is equal to the total time spent till that instant of time
   In this case you would have to take the "last" value and add it up for all the users
2. The time is equal to the small increments
   In this case you would have to add this multiple incremental value for a period of time.